# Select in SQL then use data to loop

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a select statement that obviously pulls some results from my database. Once I get those results, I would like to access them one at a time for another Select statement, is that possible? I am doing this in a user defined function.

Example:

```
SELECT differentKindsOfBread FROM breadDrawer
WHERE differentKindsOfBread IS NOT Null
```

Now I want to use my results to do another Select like:

```
SELECT differentKindsOfBread[1] FROM differentKindsOfBread
WHERE blah = blahblah
```

*EDIT*
Lets say differentKindsOfBread selected:

```
 Rye
 White
 Wheat
 half-Wheat
```

Now I want to do selects for each one like:

```
Select Rye (differntKindsOfBread[0]) ...
Select White (differntKindsOfBread[1]) ...
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am really sorry. My answer was for SQL Server. I just noticed you are using a different server.

Comment: any other solutions? :p

Comment: It seems it is close to SQL Server. Would you care to check this http://www.developitnow.com/Articles/tabid/280/EntryId/11/How-to-Create-a-Pervasive-10-Cursor.aspx

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: my goal is to select rows using one select statement, then using each row from that selection, do another selection on each row from the first selection. I think a nested select statement would work?